# Unresponsive buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason I have a bug in my code, which is causing some buttons to be unresponsive.

Can any body see any errors in my code?

```js
$('#arrowbutton').click(function(){
    console.log('arrowbutton clicked');  
    $('#code2').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 350)
})
```

```css
#arrow{
    margin-left:384px;
    z-index:15;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:25px;
    z-index:20;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<a id="arrowbutton"> <img src="images/step-22.png" id="arrow"> </a>
```

I am not getting any errors and I am not getting the `console.log()` message either.

Any reasons why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: You need to have an href attribute on your a tag

Comment: Do you have more than one button with the id #arrowbutton ? (it's not clear here, so this is a guess) If so - ids need to be unique and you should change it to a class instead?

Comment: @Sam Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @LyeFish My mistake. You don't need the href to make it work. The code in the question works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/c6gjctys/1/. Could be lack of jQuery as mentioned above.

Comment: you beauty! using a class made it work. thanks a lot @TarynEast

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one button with the id `#arrowbutton` it can get confused - or only put the event on one or just break (depending on which browser you use)

ids need to be unique to an html page
So if you want more than one link to have this behaviour, then you should change it to a class instead.

eg

```
<a class="arrowbutton"> <img src="images/step-22.png" id="arrow"> </a> 

$('.arrowbutton').click(function(){
    console.log('arrowbutton clicked');  
    $('#code2').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 350);
});
```

(Note: not actually tested, could be buggy)

Comment: thanks. hopefully got all the right semicolons (again, not actually tested) ;)